# Rust как разделить текст по символам?

Tags: массивы, rust, split

Появилась проблема, что надо разделить строку `let st = "Hello world"` на
символы, но `st.split("");` не помогает. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Какой тип данных вы хотите получить в итоге? `Vec<char>`, `&[u8]` или что-то совсем другое?

Comment: `st.chars()`, не?

Comment: string хочу получить

Comment: мне нужно допустим массив получить в котором будет строки H, e, l, l, o, , w, o, r, l ,d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так должно работать:

```rust
    let chars : Vec<char> = st.chars().collect();
```

Но, вообще говоря, для большинства задач отдельный вектор символов будет избыточен, и вам достаточно итератора `st.chars()`

Если вам нужно разбить именно на подстроки - можете сделать вот так:

```rust
    let chars : Vec<&str> = st.split_inclusive(|_| { true }).collect();
```

Здесь замыкание говорит о том, что любой символ является разделителем, а суффикс `_inclusive` говорит включать разделитель в выходную строку (без него у вас будет вектор пустых подстрок).

Comment: так мне надо строку

Comment: чтобы символ был в строковом формате, такое возможно?

Comment: спасибо сработало

Comment: на всякий дополню, что в современном юникоде можно разные штуки под символом понимать - и в общем случае с точки зрения пользователя символом логичнее называть не кодпоинт (который char в расте), а графемный кластер. Для итерации по последним в общепринятой библиотеке [unicode-segmentation](https://crates.io/crates/unicode-segmentation) есть итератор `graphemes`.